# Let {$a_{n}$} be a sequence with $0 \lt a_1 \lt 1$, and $a_{n+1}=a_n(1-a_{n})$. Prove $\lim_{n\to \infty}n a_{n}=1$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Problem: Let {$a_{n}$} be a sequence with $0 \lt a_1 \lt 1$, and $a_{n+1}=a_n(1-a_{n})$. Prove $\lim_{n\to \infty}n a_{n}=1$.

My try: I have figured out {$a_{n}$} is decreasing and converges to $0$. But how can I relate it to {${na_{n}}$} ?

Any hint to start, thanks!

Comment: I think this problem was given at Putnam, 1966.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $(a_n)_n$ is eventually decreasing to $0^+$ then $(1/a_n)_n$  is a strictly increasing and divergent sequence, and we can use [Stolz-Cesaro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem):
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}n a_{n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n}{1/a_n}
\stackrel{\text{SC}}{=}\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(n+1)-n}{1/a_{n+1}-1/a_n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{a_n(1-a_n)}-\frac{1}{a_n}}=
\lim_{n\to \infty}(1-a_n)=1.$$